# Pushing SQL Server logins via chef

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, chef-infra, configurationmanager, cookbook

I was wondering if it were possible to push a SQL Server login via a chef recipe, without going through something like PowerShell. We already push an RBAC file to maintain users on a DB on creation time, but I would like to be able to also push logins for SQL Server via chef. I see that there's a sql_server cookbook, but it seems like it's mainly for installing/configuring SQL Servers, and there doesn't seem to be an option to push a specific login with a log in name and hash.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, this isn't a feature of the `sql_server` cookbook. At it's heart, Chef is just running commands and manipulating files so if you know how to do whatever is required to create a SQL Server user from the command line, you can write a Chef recipe for it. Check out the `execute` and `powershell_script` resources as a starting point. There is also some integration with the Microsoft DSC system which might already have resource types for this.